# Yet another dependency problem during wine install on Devuan 5

Tags: apt, dependencies, wine, devuan

Using Devuan 5, trying to install `wine-staging` using the WineHQ repositories gives a dependency error : winehq-staging needs wine-staging.

(if you really need the precise error when running `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging`
i'll let it here but it's all in french:)

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 winehq-staging : Dépend: wine-staging (= 8.17~bookworm-1)
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

So I run `sudo apt install wine-staging` and I get this dependency error (sorry it's also in french):

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libavahi-client3 : Dépend: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) mais il n'est pas installable
 libpcap0.8 : Dépend: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) mais il n'est pas installable
 libpulse0 : Dépend: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) mais il n'est pas installable
```

So they basically all need this magic `libdbus-1-3` package at a version higher or equal to 1.9.14. However when I run `sudo apt install libdbus-1-3`, it's already installed AND way higher than the asked version:

```
libdbus-1-3 est déjà la version la plus récente (1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
```

So I guess that the specific devuan version broke whatever software checks for dependencies but what should I do now? Can I / Should I force the install? I don't really have a clue

EDIT: output of

```
$ LANG=C apt policy libdbus-1-3:{amd64,i386}                                   
libdbus-1-3:
  Installed: 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1
  Candidate: 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1
  Version table:
 *** 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.14.6-1devuan1 500
        500 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main amd64 Packages
libdbus-1-3:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.14.6-1devuan1
  Version table:
     1.14.6-1devuan1 500
        500 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libdbus-1-3:
  Installed: 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1
  Candidate: 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1
  Version table:
 *** 1.14.8-1~deb12u1devuan1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.14.6-1devuan1 500
        500 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main amd64 Packages
libdbus-1-3:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.14.6-1devuan1
  Version table:
     1.14.6-1devuan1 500
        500 http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus/main i386 Packages
```

means that your installed version of `libdbus-1-3` is no longer available from your configured repositories. As a result, `apt` can’t install a matching version of `libdbus-1-3:i386`, which is required for Wine.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. You could downgrade `libdbus-1-3` to the version currently available to you; you’d need to do this for any other package similarly affected. To do this, run

   ```
   sudo apt install libdbus-1-3=1.14.6-1devuan1
   ```

   You can then try installing Wine again, and use the same `apt policy` technique to determine how to downgrade any other affected package.
2. You could add the “proposed-updates” repository; `apt` will then be able to upgrade `libdbus-1-3:amd64` and install a matching version of `libdbus-1-3:i386`. This will work for all similarly affected packages, automatically:

   ```
   echo deb http://deb.devuan.org/devuan daedalus-proposed-updates main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt update
   ```

   At this point you might *not* want to run `apt upgrade`, but instead just try installing Wine again. If you do run `apt upgrade`, you’ll apply any available proposed update; this shouldn’t have any adverse consequences, but might not be desirable if you want to keep things simple.

   Once you’ve installed Wine, you can remove the “proposed-updates” line. The rest of the system will catch up with the upgraded packages when the next Devuan 5 point release is published.

Comment: Thanks the second one worked ! However I would just like to point out that the first one does not.